# MySQL Update a table on these arrays?

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I have a query like so:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(wp.`ID`), wps.sku AS sku
FROM `wp_posts` AS wp
INNER JOIN `wp_postmeta` AS wpm ON (wpm.`post_id` = wp.`ID` AND wpm.`meta_key` = '_sku' AND wpm.`meta_value` = '')
INNER JOIN `wp_product_skus` AS wps ON (wps.`id_product` = wpm.`post_id`)
WHERE wp.`post_parent` = 0 AND wp.`post_type` = 'product' AND wp.`ID` NOT IN (SELECT post_parent FROM wp_posts WHERE post_parent != 0 AND post_type = 'product_variation')
```

It returns output like so:

[image: Select query]

I need to perform an UPDATE on all IDs that match in the `wp_postmeta` table with the `post_id` = `ID` and update the meta_value of `sku` with the value of the sku from the above pic.

How can I do this all from within a MySQL Query?

Comment: there are multiple mysql queries on here that will show you how. did you do any research first? google search 'MySQL update table with select'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to perform a `UPDATE` with `JOIN` to other tables as needed like

```
UPDATE `wp_posts` wp
INNER JOIN `wp_postmeta` wpm ON wpm.`post_id` = wp.`ID` 
AND wpm.`meta_key` = '_sku' 
AND wpm.`meta_value` = ''
INNER JOIN `wp_product_skus` wps ON wps.`id_product` = wpm.`post_id`
WHERE wp.`post_parent` = 0 
AND wp.`post_type` = 'product' 
AND wp.`ID` NOT IN (
SELECT post_parent FROM wp_posts 
WHERE post_parent != 0 
AND post_type = 'product_variation'
)
SET wp.sku = wps.sku
```

(OR) By directly joining with your `SELECT` result set like below

```
UPDATE `wp_posts` wp
JOIN 
(
SELECT DISTINCT wp.`ID`, 
wps.sku AS sku
FROM `wp_posts` wp
INNER JOIN `wp_postmeta` AS wpm ON wpm.`post_id` = wp.`ID` 
AND wpm.`meta_key` = '_sku' 
AND wpm.`meta_value` = ''
INNER JOIN `wp_product_skus` wps ON wps.`id_product` = wpm.`post_id`
WHERE wp.`post_parent` = 0 
AND wp.`post_type` = 'product' 
AND wp.`ID` NOT IN (
SELECT post_parent FROM wp_posts 
WHERE post_parent != 0 
AND post_type = 'product_variation') 
) TAB ON wp.ID = TAB.ID
SET wp.sku = TAB.sku
```

Comment: Updating the `wp_postmeta` table, but this worked just the same for that table.  Cheers :)

Comment: Great. then a +1 may be :)